# Conditional operator, simplified way to check result after addition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm working on a game for a friend, and in the stat building part of the class I have a part that adds basic modifiers to the stats based on the class (warrior, mage, etc) however the final stat cannot be less than zero.

Currently there's this:

```
this.stats[i] += type[i];
if(this.stats[i] < 0) {
    this.stats[i] = 0;
}
```

Which is fine, a bit redundent, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a single line. I doubt it, but I was curious to see if I may be wrong.

Something like:

```
this.stats[i] += type[i] < 0 ? // etc;
```

But I know that will just run the conditional before adding the variable to the current `int`. Also, yes, working with integers only, no floats or strings or whatever, that's taken care of elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignments like `+=` return the assigned value. If the operator precedence is not like you want, just add parentheses.

```
if((this.stats[i] += type[i]) < 0) this.stats[i] = 0;
```

But probably a `Math.max` is clearer:

```
this.stats[i] = Math.max(0, this.stats[i] + type[i]);
```

Comment: `Math.max`, you know I always seem to overlook the built in functionality of JavaScript. Thank you and I'll accept your answer in 3 mins when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in one line but it won't be very simple, cause you have to check sum of `this.stats[i] + type[i]`

```
this.stats[i] = (this.stats[i] + type[i]) < 0 ? 0 : (this.stats[i] + type[i]).
```

So, you can add variable here

```
var sum = this.stats[i] + type[i];
this.stats[i] = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
```